# NPM Error when publishing during pipeline build on .Net Core app on Azure DevOps

Tags: .net, reactjs, azure, asp.net-core, pipeline

I have a .NET Core React application trying to deploy on Azure DevOps with CI/CD Pipeline.
So far my build succeeds, next is Publish and Publish Build Artifact.

My issue is on build pipeline, when publishing, an error interrupts:

It makes no sense for permission to be denied, I admin everything. When it comes to "npm run build --prod", I have chaned it from "npm run build-- --prod" and also running this command on its own does not produce any errors either.

> React@0.1.0 build /home/vsts/work/1/s/MyApp/ReactApp
> react-scripts build

sh: 1: react-scripts: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! React@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the React@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2019-05-22T10_48_49_127Z-debug.log
/home/vsts/work/1/s/MyApp/MyApp.csproj(45,3): error MSB3073: The command "npm run build --prod" exited with code 126.

### [error]Error: The process '/usr/bin/dotnet' failed with exit code 1

### [error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : /home/vsts/work/1/s/MyApp/MyApp.csproj

### [section]Finishing: DotNetCoreCLI

Comment: Can you upload your package.json file and screen shot project structure for me please